# How can I convert an ascii raster format file to tiff using python?

Tags: python, ascii, raster

I have a ascii raster format file. For example:

```
ncols 480
nrows 450
xllcorner 378923
yllcorner 4072345
cellsize 30
nodata_value -32768
43 2 45 7 3 56 2 5 23 65 34 6 32 54 57 34 2 2 54 6 
35 45 65 34 2 6 78 4 2 6 89 3 2 7 45 23 5 8 4 1 62 ...
```

How can I convert it to tiff or any other raster using python?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  I don't know if it supports that ASCII format, but you could parse the numbers with Python (e.g. `[map(int, line.split()) for line in file.xreadlines()]` after advancing `file` past the header).

With PIL, you have two options:

1. Create a PIL [Image](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) object and use `putpixel` to set the pixel values one at a time (slow).
2. Create a [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array representing the image and use `Image.fromarray(array)` to convert it all at once (fast, after you've build the Numpy array).

PIL has methods for writing out to many different file formats, [including TIFF](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-tiff.htm).